# Ошибка "self" is not definded

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

> "self" is not defined [85, 13]
> [86, 13]
> [87, 13]

```
from ast import Try
from lib2to3.refactor import get_all_fix_names
import os
from re import T
from select import select #Загрузка модулей
import sys
from tkinter import RIGHT
from tkinter.tix import Tree
from turtle import left, right, up, speed
import pygame
import time
import random
import shutil
import webbrowser

pygame.init() #Инициализация pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

clear = lambda : os.system('cls') #Очистка.
clear()


#def vstuplenie(): #Вход после пароля!
#    print("Ожидается ввод пароля...")
#    password = input()
#    if password == "04221":
#        clear()
#        pass
#    else:
#        clear()
#        print("Неверный пароль! Попробуйте ещё раз!")
#        return vstuplenie()
#vstuplenie()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0),pygame.FULLSCREEN) #полный экран
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Adventure") #Название игры

playerx = 0 #Координаты игрока
playery = 540
speed = 30.5

game = True

#Загрузка картинок и спрайтов
SPpow = [pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SHpow1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SHpow2.png'), pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SHpow3.png')]
playerStand = [pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH1.png'),
pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH2.png'), pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH3.png'),
pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH4.png'), pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH5.png'),
pygame.image.load('paint\planer\SHsprite\SH6.png')]
phon = pygame.image.load('paint\game\GameScreen.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Ppow = False
animCount = 0
facing = 1
bullets = []

class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y),
        self.radius)

def drawWindow(): #Отрисовка
    global animCount
    global Ppow
    win.blit(phon, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >=30:
        Ppow = False
        animCount = 0
    if Ppow == True:
        win.blit(SPpow[animCount // 10], (playerx, playery))
        animCount += 10
        if animCount == 30:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(playerx, playery, 8, 32)
            self.color = 200, 0, 0
            self.speed = 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand[animCount // 5], (playerx, playery))
        animCount += 3
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()

while game:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                animCount = 0
                Ppow = True
                if len(bullets) < 5:
                    bullets.append(snaryad(round(playerx + 64), round(playery + 
                    128), 20, (255, 0, 0), facing))
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 1920:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playery < 960 and playerx < 832:
        playerx += speed
        playery += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playery < 960 and playerx > 0:
        playerx -= speed
        playery += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playery > 0 and playerx < 832:
        playerx += speed
        playery -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playery > 0 and playerx > 0:
        playerx -= speed
        playery -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerx > 0:
        playerx -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerx < 832:
        playerx += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and playery > 0:
        playery -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and playery < 960:
        playery += speed
    pygame.display.update()
    drawWindow()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Крашится всё и вылезает ошибка.

Comment: `def drawWindow(): #Отрисовка` тут нет self

Comment: Что нужно вписать? Если не секрет.

Comment: @entithat Попробовал сделать def drawWindow(self):

Comment: Вылезла ошибка про конец. Написал там теперь там ошибка

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете что такое self ? откуда он возьмется у функции, которая не является членом класса. В тех строках где говорит, что self не объявлен явно должно быть что то другое, а точнее тот объект, свойства которого вы пытаетесь менять. А вот что это за объект это вам виднее.